# Breakpoint will not be hit in silverlight running on azure dev fabric

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, azure, wcf-ria-services

I'm building application using WCF RIA services and silverlight running on azure dev fabric. I have a solution with silverlight client projects, a Web client project and WCF projects.  I placed breakpoints in silverlight project and WCF project (in app.xaml.cs) so I can step thru the code on both side. I break in my WCF code but I can’t jump in the silverlight code.  When I looked at the silverlight breakpoint while debugging, the red dot displays an exclamation mark and this message: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit".

I’ve done several things to solve this:

- Made sure that the ClientBin folder contains the correct .xap file.
  The folder contains the correct xap.
- Checked the solution if it was in release mode, but apparently I was
  in Debug mode
- Checked if silverlight debugging is enabled in web site, yes it was
  enabled. I’m able to debug the silverlight running on separate
  instance (not in azure).
- Deleted bin/debug and or bin/obj folder but still no good
- Deleted the ClientBin folder on silverlight's web role end
  point
- Deleted the source codes and then retrieve them again from source
  control to check if there’s change in source control, still no good.
  Apparently the solution in other developer’s workstation works fine, I’m 
  the only one having this problem.
- Reset the iis using iisreset, still nothing good happened
- Cleared the browser's cache (I’m using IE9), nothing good
  happened.

Anyone ever met this situation? Any answer other than re-installing would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you've already tried a lot ;) Can you try with another browser. Can you also check the output window of your Debugging VS instance.

Comment: I tried with firefox 4 (already configured for silverlight debugging), still nothing happened to the breakpoints.
Output window showed nothing when debugging instance.

Comment: I'm sure you've done it (you've done everything else already), but have you done a full reboot of the machine?

Comment: I did full reboot my workstation. Still nothing good happens.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this case on new solution with new azure, silverlight and wcf project and everything works fine. There was no problem in debugging either silverlight or wcf project. 
Thus, there is nothing wrong with my VS or browser setting.

I tried to use a copy of the other developer's solution and there's no trouble in debugging. I have no idea why such thing could happens because the solution is basically the same (All of the csproj.user and suo files are not checked in to source control.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Solution >> Properties >> Set the silverlight project as the startup project.